# Реализация поиска по базе json через parsecloud

Tags: javascript, json, parse.com

Учусь делать приложение на *iOS*, бэкенд на *parse.com*.

Пытаюсь сделать поиск машин по базе (*json-файл* залил на *parse*, установил *parse cloud*).

Может, у кого-то был опыт? Как примерно будет выглядеть функция поиска?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: а в чём, собственно, вопрос? о наличии опыта? изложите, пожалуйста, возникшую у вас проблему, в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так:

1. К каждому классу, по которому необходим поиск, добавлял поле
   searchTerms (массив строк)
2. В фукнции beforeSave класса разбирал содержимое и редактировал массив searchTerms. Например разбирал на слова название, категорию и обновлял массив.
3. Поисковый запрос опять таки разбирал на слова
4. Каждое слово добавлял в объект Parse.Query в цикле 
   query.contains("searchTerms", value);